# ¿Como agregarle minutos a una hora en un input datetime-local?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy copiando el valor de un input de tipo datetime-local(fecha_ini) a otro una vez que el usuario escribe en el primero(fecha_ter). Sin embargo me gustaria poder agregarle 20 minutos más al resultado en el segundo input(fecha_ter)¿Como podría hacerlo ?

```
$("#fecha_ini").keyup(function(){

   var value = $(this).val();
   $("#fecha_ter").val(value);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la función de [.setMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) puedes hacerlo sin ningun problema

```
$("#fecha_ini").keyup(function(){

   var value = $(this).val();
   $("#fecha_ter").val(value.AddMinutes(20));
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, aunque al escribir en el input ahora no se agrega ningún valor.

Comment: Entonces colocalo en una nueva variable

Comment: Revise la respuesta editada, pero aun así tampoco lo hace, creo que se debe al formato del datetime-local que es ejemplo:  20/10/2017 13:30

Comment: Bueno, otra función del datime es AddMinutes();

Comment: No, no funca, igual gracias por responder